# Powershell giving different execution policy in different permissions

Tags: powershell

[Image : Execution Policy in admin vs non-admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DwXw6.png)

I did a fresh Windows 10 install and ran this de-bloater script (https://github.com/Sycnex/Windows10Debloater).
Later I checked the execution policy, and in *Powershell as administrator*, it comes out "**Restricted**"  & in *non-admin powershell* it says "**Bypass**".

Non-admin mode doesn't allow execution policy to be changed. Is there any way to make it "**Restricted**" everywhere like it was before running the script on a fresh install.

TLDR: Execution Policy got changed to "**Bypass**". How can I reset the execution policy to its default ("**Restricted**") on a new Windows 10 Install.

Comment: Just set it at the machine level. How you start user/process sessions is up to you. Please remember, as per all MS docs,  EP's are not a security boundary and can be easily bypassed to run code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just run

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy Restricted
```

as admin and it will change for the user as well, since the default scope for the command is "LocalMachine". No need to even restart PowerShell if you have it running as user.

Comment: It did the trick. Now admin and non-admin both "get-executionpolicy" show "restricted" :)